# Odd issue with OR operator in zsh

Tags: linux, centos, zsh, conditional-statements

I'm seeing an odd issue with CentOS 6.4, zsh 4.3.10 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

This is running two regular expressions on the same string. Neither expression passes the if conditional, but when I OR them together

```
$ if [[ "foo" =~ "^\s*$" ]]; then; echo "Test"; fi
$ if [[ "foo" =~ "^\.+$" ]]; then; echo "Test"; fi
$ if [[ "foo" =~ "^\.+$" || "foo" =~ "^\s*$" ]]; then; echo "OR test"; fi
OR test
```

This only happens on CentOS as far as I can tell, I get expected behavior with zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0) and zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last if should be slightly different if or is desired. Try:

```
if [[ "foo" =~ "^\.+$" ]] || [[ "foo" =~ "^\s*$" ]]; then; echo "OR test"; fi
```

Comment: Josip, this solves my issue, thanks. You may be interested in my email at http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2014/msg00500.html